# problem with video masking, video size is full width, cannot cover under svg logo

Tags: html, svg, video, mask, rect

I have a problem with video masking. The video size is full width but cannot cover under SVG logo.

here is [link](http://urban.garotanzi.com/?page_id=59)

```
<div class="video-mask-otr">
<video class="bg-video" autoplay playsinline muted loop preload src=" http://urban.garotanzi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Background-Movie.mp4"></video>

    <svg class="banner" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 273.46 223.7"><title>4Asset 1</title>

        <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
             <defs>
                 <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"> 
                      <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
                 <path d="M0,0V95A128.75,128.75,0,0,0,128.75,223.7h0V0Z"/><polygon points="144.72 223.7 273.46 223.7 273.46 0.7 144.72 223.7">     </mask>
            </defs>
            <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"  id="mask-bg"></rect>
            </g></g></svg>

</div>
```

Comment: before asking question refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes. 
There are tags without closing.
The width/height ratio of your svg is not the same as the width/height ratio of video. I've changed the svg's `viewBox` to `"0 0 273.46 153.82"`.

A thing to know about masks is that unlike real masks, you will see only through the mask. In your case inside the mask you have a rect as big as the svg, so the mask is as big as the svg and you will see everything beneath. I've removed this rect.

And now it works but there is still one problem. The mask is not what you intend, but exactly the opposite.The solution to this is going back to the drawing board and redraw the path for the mask.

```css
body{background:black}
.video-mask-otr video,.video-mask-otr svg{position:absolute;top:0;}
```

```html
<div class="video-mask-otr">
<video class="bg-video" autoplay playsinline muted loop preload src=" http://urban.garotanzi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Background-Movie.mp4" width="100%"></video>

<svg class="banner" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 273.46 153.82"><title>4Asset 1</title>

        <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
             <defs>
                 <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"> 
                 <!--<rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>-->
                 <path fill="white" d="M0,0V95A128.75,128.75,0,0,0,128.75,223.7h0V0Z"/>
                 <polygon  fill="white"  points="144.72 223.7 273.46 223.7 273.46 0.7 144.72 223.7"/>     
               </mask>
            </defs>
            <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"  id="mask-bg" style="mask: url(#mask)"></rect>
            </g></g></svg>

</div>
```